# Inject different factories to the same actor

Tags: scala, akka, guice, actor

I'm new to Akka and Guice, and just started to explore it.

I'm trying to make a father actor, that produce child actors from one specific type, to be more generic- so it'll produce many kind of child actors with different types.

Currently- I inject to the father-actor a Factory of one specific type of actor, 
I don't want to add more cases to the father actor, I'd like to solve this problem in more elegant way.

so now I have 2 child actors, and I want to Inject their factory to the father-actor, to do so i thought that maybe I should create the father-actor twice, and each time to inject a different type of Factory.

what I would want to achieve is something like this code 
(this code is not working, but this is the idea):

Base Factory trait:

```
trait BaseFactory {
   apply(id: Int) : Actor
}
```

```
object FirstActor {
   trait Factory extends BaseFactory
}

class FirstActor (@Assisted id: Int) extends Actor with InjectedActorSupport {
   ....
}
```

```
object SecondActor {
   trait Factory extends BaseFactory
}

class SecondActor (@Assisted id: Int) extends Actor with InjectedActorSupport {
   ....
}
```

```
class Father @Inject()(factory: BaseFactory, name: String) extends Actor with InjectedActorSupport {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case Command =>
      ...
      val actor = context.child(id)
        .getOrElse(injectedChild(factory(id), name, _.withMailbox("deque-mailbox")))
  }
}
```

And then the module:
(this part is not compiling since I can't pass the Factories to props as a trait definition and not an instance)

```
class Module extends AkkaGuiceSupport {
  def configure(): Unit = {
    bindActor[ExecutorsOffice]("FirstFather", Props(new Father(FirstActor.Factory)))
    bindActor[ExecutorsOffice]("SecondFather", Props(new Father(SecondActor.Factory)))

    bindActorFactory[FirstActor, FirstActor.Factory]
    bindActorFactory[SecondActor, SecondActor.Factory]
  }
```

I'll be happy to hear your thoughts, and your solutions (other solutions will be great also!)

Comment: It would be easier to figure out the solution if you could explain what isn't working with your current solution. Does it crash? If so, what is the exception and stack trace? Does it not compile? If so, what is the compile error?

Comment: @Henrik The code is just how i would want to solve this problem.
I am not sure if i can solve it like that since it's not compiling, I cannot pass ```UpdateProcessManager.Factory``` to the Props since this is not an instance, just the definition of the trait..

Comment: @NoaCohen may I ask, you are you using Guice in Akka? You can have effective and simple DI with native Akka code. You did not elaborate on the real use case, but it seems that you are struggling with Guice, not with Akka.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you'd need Guice-injection.

```
type PropsCreator = String => Props

object ParentActor {
  def props(childPropsCreator: PropsCreator) = Props(classOf[ParentActor], childPropsCreator)
}

class ParentActor(childPropsCreator: PropsCreator) extends Actor {
  // yadda yadda yadda
  def receive(): Receive = {
    case x: Command =>
      // yadda yadda yadda
      val child = context.child(id)
        .getOrElse(context.actorOf(childPropsCreator(id), id))
      child.forward(x)
  }
}

object DdvRenderProcessManager {
  def props(id: String) = Props(classOf[DdvRenderProcessManager], id)
}

class DdvRenderProcessManager(id: String) extends Actor {
  // definition omitted
}

object UpdateProcessManager {
  def props(id: String) = Props(classOf[UpdateProcessManager], id)
}

class UpdateProcessManager(id: String) extends Actor {
  // definition omitted
}
```

Then you'd create parents like

```
val ddvRenderParent = system.actorOf(ParentActor.props(DdvRenderProcessManager.props _), "ddvRenderParent")
val updateParent = system.actorOf(ParentActor.props(UpdateProcessManager.props _), "updateParent")
```

If you wanted to, for instance have all the `DdvRenderProcessManager`s have a certain dynamic value:

```
object DdvRenderProcessManager {
  // could also express as
  //  def props(x: Int)(id: String): Props
  // and curry, but this expression is clearer about intent
  def propsFor(x: Int): String => Props = { (id: String) =>
    Props(classOf[DdvRenderProcessManager], id, x)
  }
}

class DdvRenderProcessManager(id: String, x: Int) extends Actor {
  // definition omitted
}
```

And then

```
val ddvRenderParent = system.actorOf(ParentActor.props(DdvRenderProcessManager.propsFor(42)), "ddvRenderParent")
```

You could even make the dynamic value `implicit` to allow for something very-close to compile-time DI.